# Google Play Games Push Notifications - custom text?

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using Google Play Games to manage a Turn-Based game, and it provides functionality for push notifications, which are used mainly in the events of being invited to a battle and a player taking a turn in a battle.

I'd like to take advantage of this and customise the text that gets shown to the user in the notification. For example, Google Play Games notes that you have been invited to a 'match', whereas we use the terminology 'battle'. This creates issues with the user experience.

Is there any way to customise these notifications?

Comment: Note that another option would be to write your own custom notifications with [OnInvitationReceivedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Invitations.html#registerInvitationListener)